# Find all the planar surfaces in an rgbd image using depth and normal data

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, raytracing

Many questions deal with generating normal from depth or depth from normal, but I want to ask about a simple way to generate all the planar surfaces given the depth and normal of an image.

I already have depth and normal of each pixel in the image. For each pixel `(ui, vi)`, assume that we can get its 3D coordinates `(xi, yi, zi)` with `zi` as the depth and normal vector `(nix, niy, niz)`. Thus, a unique tangent plane is defined by: `nix(x - xi) + niy(y - yi) + niz(z - zi) = 0.` Then, for each pixel we can define a unique planar surface by the above equation.

1. What is a common practice in finding the function `f` such that `f(u, v) = (x, y, z)` (from pixel to 3D coordinates)? Is pinhole model (plus the depth data) an effective and accurate one?
2. How does one generate all the planar surfaces effectively? One way is to iterate through all the pixels in the image and find all the planes, but this seems like an ineffective method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **If its pinhole model**

   make sure your 3D data is not distorted by projection.
2. **group your points by normal**

   this is easy or hard depending on the points/normal accuracy. Simply sort the points by normals which leads to `O(n.log(n))` where `n` is number of points.
3. **test/group by planes in  single normal group**

   The idea is to pick 3 points from a group compute plane from it and test which points of the group belongs to it. If too low count you got wrong points picked (not belonging to the same plane) and need to pick different ones. Also if the picked points are too close to each or on the same line you can not get correct plane from it.

   The math function for plane is:

   ```
   x*nx + y*ny + z*nz + d = 0
   ```

   where `(nx,ny,nz)` is your normal of the group (unit vector) and `(x,y,z)` is your point position. So you just compute `d` from a known point (one of the picked ones `(x0,y0,z0)` ) ...

   ```
   d = -x0*nx -y0*ny -z0*nz
   ```

   and then just test which points are sattisfying this condition:

   ```
   threshod=1e-20; // just accuracy margin
   fabs(x*nx + y*ny + z*nz + d) <= threshod
   ```

   now remove matched points from the group (move them into found plane object) and apply this bullet again on the remaining points until they count is low or no valid plane is found...

   then test another group until no groups are left...

I think **RANSAC** can speed things up to avoid brute force in this case but never used it myself so google ...

Comment: Can you clarify on "If too low count you got wrong points picked (not belonging to the same plane)"? Say I have `n` points belong to the same normal group. Then I pick point `(x0, y0, z0)`, derive the plane equation (threshold and stuff as you said), and then test which points are satisfying that equation for ALL other points in the group. Is this what you are talking about? I'm confused about `pick 3 points`.

Comment: @SparklesLeet you can have more parallel planes in your data and if you chose points with the same normal but not from the same plane then the majority of points will not satisfy such plane hinting you picked wrong combination of first 3 points. Also on edges of objects the normal is changing rapidly so its possible group normal does not correspond to any plane in such case group would be less populated then other groups and there will be no plane with majority of points also ... so in both cases you detect plane with very small amount of points like <1% of group population...

Comment: @SparklesLeet ad yes you pick 3 points (randomly or by geometric distance to each etc) derive the plane from it and test which points satisfy such plane from the rest of the points in the same normal group ...

Comment: Why do we need 3 points? I thought 1 point (and of course its normal vector) is enough to derive the plane from it.

Comment: @SparklesLeet oow yes totally forget  you got normals already ... so one point is enough now I see your confusion ... the 3 points are necessary only when you do not know the normal.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach for the planes is to consider the set of normal vectors and perform clustering on them (for instance by k-means). Then every cluster can correspond to several parallel surfaces. By evaluating the distance from the origin (a scalar function), you can form sub-clusters which will separate those surfaces. Finally, points at constant distance can belong to different coplanar patches, which you can separate by connected component labelling.

It is likely that clustering on the normal vectors and distance simultaneously (hence in a 4D space) will yield better results and be simpler. Be sure to normalize the vectors. Another option is to represent the vectors by just two parameters (such as spherical angles), but this will lead to a quite non-uniform mapping, and create phase wrapping issues.

Comment: How do you form sub-clusters in this case? Say I now have a cluster of pixels that have the very close normal vector to each other (belong to several parallel surfaces as you said).  How do you form sub-clusters by evaluating the distance from the origin?

Comment: @SparklesLeet: you compute all the distances. And cluster them.